# C++ function returned value not assigned

Tags: c++, function, return, assign

I encountered a weird bug

I am returning a pointer, before return, I verified that the pointer is valid & has memory
However, after the function scope, when I tried to use the return value in main(), it becomes NULL.
I also tried to return the dereferenced value of the pointer, it is a modified struct before return, and an unmodified struct in main()..

This is supposed to be like a dictionary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "trie.h"

using namespace std;

int alphaLoc(char segment){
    return (int)segment - 97;
}

//inserts a word in the tree
void insert(TrieNode &node, const std::string &word){
    int locationInAlphabet = alphaLoc(word[0]);
    if (node.letters[locationInAlphabet] == NULL){
        node.letters[locationInAlphabet] = new TrieNode;
    }
    if (word.length() == 1){
        if (node.letters[locationInAlphabet]->isWord == true){
            cout<<"Word Already Exsit"<<endl;
        }
        node.letters[locationInAlphabet]->isWord = true;
    }
    else{
        insert(*(node.letters[locationInAlphabet]), word.substr(1,word.length()-1));
    }
}

//returns the node that represents the end of the word
TrieNode* getNode(const TrieNode &node, const std::string &word){
    int locationInAlphabet = alphaLoc(word[0]);
    if (node.letters[locationInAlphabet] == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        if (word.length() == 1){
            return (node.letters[locationInAlphabet]);
        }
        else{
            getNode(*(node.letters[locationInAlphabet]), word.substr(1,word.length()-1));
        } 
    }
}

int main(){
    TrieNode testTrie;
    insert(testTrie, "abc");
    cout<< testTrie.letters[0]->letters[1]->letters[2]->isWord<<endl;
    cout<<"testing output"<<endl; 
    cout<< getNode(testTrie, "abc")->isWord << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

And the output is :

```
1
testing output
Segmentation fault: 11
```

trie.h:

```
#include <string>

struct TrieNode {
    enum { Apostrophe = 26, NumChars = 27 };
    bool isWord;
    TrieNode *letters[NumChars];
    TrieNode() {
        isWord = false;
         for ( int i = 0; i < NumChars; i += 1 ) {
             letters[i] = NULL;
         } // for
    }
}; // TrieNode

void insert( TrieNode &node, const std::string &word );

void remove( TrieNode &node, const std::string &word );

std::string find( const TrieNode &node, const std::string &word );
```

Comment: Is `return` missing before `getNode(*(node...`?

Comment: @Riateche - stick this in as an answer and I'll delete mine - your comment went in just before I answered by the looks of it.

Comment: that is the recursive statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `return` missing before `getNode(*(node...`.

If this line is executed in some moment, after this execution control flow reaches the end of `getNode` function, and no `return` statement is here. It will result in undefined return value, which is always bad. You must always return something definite from your function.

Comment: no..it is supposed to be recursing till the last character of the word

Comment: Here is certainly a mistake. If this line is executed in some moment, after this execution control flow reaches the end of `getNode` function, and no `return` statement is here. It will result in undefined return value, which is always bad. You must always return something definite from your function.